# React.js: Browser freezes whenever i tried to add a react component inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and i was trying to make a simple project with it, i tried to render a single component and it works well but whenever i add another component inside that component browser freezes.

this is my component 1 just a button and a badge value inside the badge gets incremented on button clicking

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counters from './counters';
class Counter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this);
    this.printout = this.printout.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    count: 100,
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
  };
  style = {
    fontSize: '30px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  };
  label_color() {
    if (this.state.count === 0) {
      return "badge badge-warning m-2";
    }
    else {

      return "badge badge-primary m-2";
    }
  };
  renderTags() {
    if (this.state.tags.length === 0) return <p>nothing</p>;
    else {

      return (<ul>{this.state.tags.map(tag => <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>)}</ul>);

    }
  };
  printout(id) {
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Counter />
        <span className={this.label_color()}>{this.state.count}</span>
        <button onClick={() => this.printout({ id: 1 })} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">press</button>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
export default Counter;
```

and this is my second component, the component that i want to render. here i imported the Counter module which is in the same directory and i want display first component multiple times so that at the end I'll get a template containing multiple buttons and badges .

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Counter from './counters';
class Counters extends Component{

  state ={
    count: 100,
    tags : ['tag1','tag2','tag3'],
  };

  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <span >{this.state.count}</span>

          <Counter/>

        <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">press</button>
        </div>
    );
  }

  }
export default Counters;
```

and my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Counters from './components/counters';

ReactDOM.render(<Counters />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a circular dependency between both counters.

`<Counters />` component is importing `<Counter />` component, and `<Counter />` component is importing `<Counters />` component.

Remove this line from `<Counter />` component:

```
import Counters from './counters';
```

Moreover, this line should be removed as well:

```
  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Counter /> // ---------> This should be removed as it is calling itself.
        <span className={this.label_color()}>{this.state.count}</span>
        <button onClick={() => this.printout({ id: 1 })} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">press</button>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You always initialize React.Component inside its constructor and return inside render().

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an infinite loop because you're returning your Counter component inside of itself. Any time you create an infinite loop this will cause the browser to freeze as all of your computer's memory is consumed.

Here's a codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-breeze-8rfkt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark